# Javascript: How to get the parent key inside a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've some functions, stored in a collection/array and would like to get the key (function-name) without retyping it. Is there any short way to access it?

```
var functions_collection = {
    "function_x": function() {
        var name = "function_x";
        // name = this.key; <- how to get the key/function-name "function_x"?

        // some more code like:
        $(".function_x .button").val();

        alert(name);
    }
}
```

Edit: I'd like to avoid retyping the "function_x" inside the function itself and prefer to call it like this.key.

Sorry for the weird topic and thanks in advance!

**Solution**: A lot of good answers, but I was just looking for this snipped:

```
Object.keys(this)
```

Comment: can you give the use case, why you need this?

Comment: @itz2k13 There are some CSS-classes named as the functions. Inside the function I need to use them like $(".function_x .button").html("123"); and would like to keep my code as clean as possible.

Comment: You can call `var name = Object.keys(this)` (or use getOwnPropertyNames) to get a list of the keys in the object. Won't get you just the parent key unless there is only one ?

Comment: Why don't you use your CSS-class name as a parameter for a function?

Comment: @adeneo your answer is all I need, I guess. Why did you just post a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you where just trying to get the key names or the callee name, as everyone was posting answers to get the name of the actual key that had the called function as a value? I'll post it as an answer then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the name of the objects keys, you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)` or in newer browsers just `Object.keys(this)`, and that will get you an array of all and any keys the `this` object has :

```
var functions_collection = {
    function_x: function() {
        var name = Object.keys(this);
        console.log(name);
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GfjNE/)

Comment: This will get you all key names as an array, not just the one calling the console.log... http://jsbin.com/guhoxeqajo/edit?js,console

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure it's what you want but you can do this :

```
    var functions_collection = {};
    (function(name){
       functions_collection[name] = function(){
           // use name, which is the function
           alert(name);
       };
    })("function_x");
```

I'm not really sure it's better. But depending on your (unspecified) goal, there's probably a better solution.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but very good to know for some code in the future. Thanks a lot! +1

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion you´d need to change you above code since you are having anonymous functions which **have no name** - a change like this should work:

```
var functions_collection = {
  'function_x' : function function_x () {
    var myName = arguments.callee.name;
    alert(myName);
  }
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/9cN5q/1/

Comment: +1, But I am curious why on the local this doesn't work, but in jsFiddle, it works.

Comment: This only works if you type your function name two times in a declaration. The most common way is assigning anonymous function to an object property (gives "" in alert).

Comment: If it is anonymous it HAS NO name, thats why its called anonymous ;)

Comment: In the OP's question it IS anonymous. He wants to know the object's key for which the function was called.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it was probably because [`arguments.callee` is considered bad practice.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you could go here. Some are good ideas, some are not.

### First, some bad ideas

1. Bad idea: **`arguments.callee.name`**

   This translates most directly to what you ask. `arguments.callee` is
   a reference to the function you're currently in. However, [**it's
   considered bad
   practice,**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)
   and you should avoid using it unless you have a really good reason.
2. Bad idea: **Currying**

   After constructing the function, bind its own name into it as a parameter:

   ```
   var functions_collection = {
       "function_x": function(name) {
           alert(name);
       },
       //more functions
   };
   for (var name in functions_collection) {
       if (typeof functions_collection[name] === "function") {
           functions_collection[name] = 
               functions_collection[name].bind(functions_collection, name);
       }
   }
   ```

   Currying is useful for lots of things in JavaScript, and it's a great idea in many situations. Not here, though, and I'll explain why below.
3. Bad idea: **Use a local parameter and iterate through the containing object**

   ```
   var functions_collection = {
        "function_x": function(name) {
            alert(name);
        },
        //more functions
   };
   for (var name in functions_collection) {
       if (typeof functions_collection[name] === "function") {
           functions_collection[name](name);
       }
   }
   ```

   Of course, the obvious problem with this one is that you might not want to call every function in the collection at once. The more fundamental problem is that it continues the trend of dangerously tight coupling. This is a bad thing, potentially a Very Bad Thing that will cost you all kinds of headaches down the line.

### Now the "right" way

Change your whole approach. Forget trying to recycle class names from your HTML; just keep it simple.

1. Good idea: **Use a local variable**

   Who cares what you name your functions? If you know which HTML classes you want them to touch, just code them that way.

   ```
   var functions_collection = {
       "function_x": function() {
            var name = "function_x"; //or "button" or any other class name
            alert(name);
        },
        //more functions
   };
   functions_collection.function_x();
   ```
2. Good idea: **Pass a parameter**

   You're already calling the function, right? So there's probably already code somewhere with access to the name you want.

   ```
   var functions_collection = {
       "function_x": function(name) {
            alert(name);
        },
        //more functions
   };

   functions_collection.function_x("function_x"); //or any other class name
   ```

   Now you can use `function_x` on any class in your HTML, even if it doesn't match the function name:

   ```
   functions_collection.function_x("function_y");
   functions_collection.function_x("class_z");
   functions_collection.function_x("button");
   ```

   I've saved the simplest for last because I think you're making a mistake by trying to be "clever", if that makes sense. There are significant risks in your approach, and the payoff isn't going to be worth it.

### Why the bad ideas are bad and the good ideas are good

Other than the `arguments.callee.name` option, the reason 2 and 3 are bad in this case is **tight coupling.** You're coupling `function_x` to the structure of `functions_collection`; you're coupling behavior to a variable name; and worst of all, *you're coupling JS variables to the class names of HTML elements.* This will make your code extremely fragile, and when you want to change something (and you will), get ready for a world of hurt.

For example, what happens if you reorganize your HTML? The page probably breaks, since the structure of your JS has to match the classes in your HTML/CSS. You'll have to rename or rewrite `functions_collection` and all others like it, or else you'll have to carefully plan new HTML around the JS you already have.

What happens if you want to use a JS minifier? Depends, but if you allow it to change member names in object literals, it completely breaks everything and you have to start over with one of the "good" ideas.

Now, what do you get in exchange for this inflexibility? You save an extra line at the beginning of each function. Not worth it, IMHO. Just bite the bullet and keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that the variable name has the same name as its containing function:

```
var keys = [];
for (var p in functions_collection) {
    if (typeof(functions_collection[p]) == 'function') {
        keys.push(p);
    }
}
```

And there you have it, an array with all the function names.